# Showing that the isomorphism of the general linear group of a vector space with the group of invertible matrices is smooth

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions, general-linear-group

This is Example 7.3(e) from John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.

If $V$ is any real or complex vector space, $GL(V)$ denotes the set of invertible linear maps from $V$ to itself. It is a group under composition. If $V$ has finite dimension $n$, any basis for $V$ determines an isomorphism of $GL(V)$ with $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ or $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ so $GL(V)$ is a Lie group. The transition map between any two such isomorphisms is given by a map of the form $A\mapsto BAB^{-1}$ (where $B$ is the transition matrix between the two bases), which is smooth. Thus the smooth manifold structure on $GL(V)$ is independent of the choice of basis.

From here, I think the isomorphism of $GL(V)$ with $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ is $f: T \mapsto [T]_\beta$ where $[T]_\beta$ is the matrix representation of the invertible linear map in $V$ w.r.t the basis $\beta$. However, how can I show that this map is smooth? I can't think of a chart in the domain of $GL(V)$ containing $T$, $(U,\phi)$ and a chart $(V,\psi)$ containing $[T]_\beta$ such that $\psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}$ is smooth. I would greatly appreciate if anyone can help me with the construction of charts here.

Comment: Show it is a homomorphism and that should reduce you to checking smoothness near the identity map.  Many properties involving Lie groups, or more generally topological groups, can be reduced to looking at things around the identity.

Comment: From the thing you quote, it isn't clear to me that the author is suggesting that the map $[\cdot]_\beta$ should be proved to be smooth, but rather that he's considering all smooth structures on $GL(V_{\Bbb F})$ such that $[\cdot]_\beta:GL(V_{\Bbb F})\to GL(n,\Bbb F)$ is a diffeomorphism as being "standard". He then proceeds to remark that, since for all $\alpha,\beta$ there is a diffeomorphism $Q:GL(n,\Bbb F)\to GL(n,\Bbb F)$ such that $[\cdot]_\alpha=Q\circ [\cdot]_\beta$, all such structures are the same.

Comment: @KCd How do we check smoothness near the identity?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician try mapping the other way, starting in ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbf R)$ rather than in ${\rm GL}(V)$.

Comment: @KCd This is really confusing to me. I can see that the coordinates for GL$(n,\mathbb R)$ are the standard coordinates. But how do I map it to $GL(V)$? Could you please provide more details?

Comment: There is not a unique map.  Think about proving two vector spaces with the same dimension are isomorphic or two cyclic groups with the same order are isomorphic. In neither case is there a canonical map: you have to make an actual *choice* (of a basis or a generator) and use that to build a map that you prove is an isomorphism.  Anyway, look around in books or notes on Lie groups.

Comment: Since $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, the group isomorphisms you’ve described from $GL(V)$ to $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ are coordinate maps. And you’ve shown that the transition maps are smooth. So you’ve already shown that it’s a manifold, and the group isomorphisms are smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use an alternative approach based on the following three simple facts:

1. Each linear map $f : \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^m$ is smooth.
2. Each finite-dimensional real vector space $W$ has a canonical smooth structure. In fact, if $\dim W = m$, a smooth atlas $\mathcal A_W$ is obtained by taking all linear isomorphisms $W \to \mathbb R^m$, and this atlas generates the canonical smooth structure.
3. Each linear isomorphism $\phi : W \to W'$ between finite-dimensional real vector spaces is a diffeomorphism. To see this, simply use $\mathcal A_W$ and $\mathcal A_{W'}$ to represent $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ in terms of charts.

In particular, the vector space $\operatorname{End}_\mathbb R(V)$ of all linear endomorphisms on $V$ has a canonical smooth structure.

For each isomorphism $\phi : V \to \mathbb R^n$ we define
$$\phi_\# : \operatorname{End}_\mathbb R(V) \to \operatorname{End}_\mathbb R(\mathbb R^n), \phi_\#(f) = \phi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}.$$
This is an isomorphism of vector spaces.

The matrix representation of linear maps $g : \mathbb R^n \to  \mathbb R^n$ with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$ gives a canonical isomorphism of vector spaces
$$\mu : \operatorname{End}_\mathbb R(\mathbb R^n) \to \operatorname{M}(n, \mathbb R) .$$
Hence
$$\phi_* = \mu \circ \phi_\# : \operatorname{End}_\mathbb R(V) \to \operatorname{M}(n, \mathbb R)$$
is an isomorphism of real vector spaces and therefore a diffeomorphism.

Usually one reads phrases like

> we can identify $\operatorname{M}(n, \mathbb R)$ with $\mathbb R^{n^2}$.

This is true, but there are many such identifications. A nice one is writing the $n$ row vectors of a matrix $A = (a_{ij})$ one after the other which produces the isomorphism
$$\rho : \operatorname{M}(n, \mathbb R) \to  \mathbb R^{n^2}, \rho(A) = (a_{11},\ldots,a_{1n},a_{21},\ldots,a_{2n},\ldots, a_{n1},\ldots,a_{nn}) .$$
This is a diffeomorphism of smooth manifolds. Of course we can take any other isomorphism $\rho' : \operatorname{M}(n, \mathbb R) \to  \mathbb R^{n^2}$, but the above one has the benefit that it makes immediately clear that the determinant $\det :  \operatorname{M}(n, \mathbb R) \to \mathbb R$ is  continuous (even smooth). Just recall that $\det A =  \sum_{\sigma \in \mathfrak S_n} \operatorname{sign}(\sigma) a_{1\sigma(1)} \ldots a_{n\sigma(n)}$.

The continuity of $\det$ shows that $\operatorname{GL}(n, \mathbb R)$ is open in $\operatorname{M}(n, \mathbb R)$, thus it inherits  a smooth structure from $\operatorname{M}(n, \mathbb R)$. We conclude that $\operatorname{GL}(V) = \phi_* ^{-1}(\operatorname{GL}(n, \mathbb R))$ is open in $\operatorname{End}_\mathbb R(V)$, thus it also inherits  a smooth structure from $\operatorname{End}_\mathbb R(V)$.

All we need here is that $\operatorname{GL}(V)$ is open in $\operatorname{End}_\mathbb R(V)$. However, the use of a base is implicit in the above  construction (using $ \phi$).

Our construction also shows that $\phi_*$ restricts to a diffeomorphism $\operatorname{GL}(V) \to \operatorname{GL}(n, \mathbb R)$.

The situation for a complex vector space $V$ is similar. For the moment let us ignore smooth structures. As above we get an an isomorphism of complex vector spaces

$$\phi_* : \operatorname{End}_\mathbb C(V) \to \operatorname{M}(n, \mathbb C)$$
which depends on the choice of an isomorphism $\phi : V \to \mathbb C^n$.

This is pure linear algebra, no additional structures are involved so far.

Now we need the following two simple facts:

1. Each complex vector space $V$ can be regarded as a real vector space. If $\dim_\mathbb C V = n$, then $\dim_\mathbb R V = 2n$. Let us write $[V]$ when we regard $V$ as a real vector space.
2. Each $\mathbb C$-linear map $f : V \to W$ between complex vector spaces $V, W$ is $\mathbb R$-linear. More precisely, $f : [V] \to [W]$ is $\mathbb R$-linear.
   In particular, if $f$ is an isomorphism between the complex vector spaces $V, W$, then it is also an isomorphism between the real vector spaces $[V],[W]$.

Both $\operatorname{End}_\mathbb C(V)$ and $\operatorname{M}(n, \mathbb C)$ are complex vector spaces. Thus, regarding them as real vector spaces, they receive canonical smooth structures. This makes $\phi_* : \operatorname{End}_\mathbb C(V) \to \operatorname{M}(n, \mathbb C)$ a diffeomorphism.

Using the determinant $\det : \operatorname{M}(n, \mathbb C) \to \mathbb C$ we see that  $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb  C)$ is open in $M(n,\mathbb  C)$ and conclude that $\operatorname{GL}(V)$ is open in $\operatorname{End}_\mathbb C(V)$.

Comment: I think you mean $\phi_* =\mu \circ\phi_\#$, and this is continuous so $GL(V)$ must be open in End$(V)$, so what do you mean that all we need here is that GL(V) is open in End(V) but the use of a base is implicit in the above construction? And why is an isomorphism of vector spaces a diffeomorphism for $\phi_*$?

Comment: I see why it's a diffeomorphism you are using fact 1. But when we generalize to the $C^n$ case using $R^{2n}$, we can't get an isomorphism of $C^n$ with $R^{2n}$ as complex vector spaces can we? We still have to treat GL(V) as $C$-linear maps don't we?

Comment: Oh this book assumes the field to be over real numbers as it states $M(n,C)$ is $2n^2$ dimensional. So we are only considering $R$-linear maps.

Comment: @nomadicmathematician I corrected the mistake discovered in your first comment. I showed that $GL(V)$ is open in $End(V)$ by choosing an isomorphism $\phi : V \to \mathbb R^n$; this is equivalent to choosing a basis for $V$.   Each $n$-dim.  complex $V$ can be regarded as a $2n$-dim. real vector space, and $End_{\mathbb C}(V)$ is a linear subspace of $End_{\mathbb R}(V)$. This gives a smooth structure on it. It can be identified with $M(n,\mathbb C)$.

Comment: Dear Paul could you please explain a bit more why $End_{\mathbb{C}}(V)$ is a linear subspace of $End_{\mathbb{R}}(V)$ and it can be identified with $M(n,\mathbb{C})$? I'm not sure how this vector isomorphism works because in $End_{\mathbb{C}}(V)$ the scalar multiplication is by a complex number and in $M(n,\mathbb{C})$ the scalar multiplication is by a real number so if a linear map $T$ is identified with $A$ in $M(n,\mathbb{C})$, how do we interpret $\lambda\cdot T$ in $End_{\mathbb{C}}(V)$ as $c\cdot A$ in $M(n,\mathbb{C})$ with $\lambda$ complex and $c$ real?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician I made an update.

Comment: So we treat $V$ as a $2n$-dim real vector space and get an isomorphism $\phi:V \to \mathbb{C}^n_{\mathbb{R}}$, where we treat $\mathbb{C}^n$ as a real vector space. And define $\phi_{\#}:End_{\mathbb{C}}(V)\to End_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{C}^n)$ where $End_{\mathbb{C}}(V)$ is considered a real vector space. And $\mu:End_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{C}^n)\to M(n,\mathbb{C})$ is the canonical isomorphism. Is this correct? But how do we know that the inverse of $\phi_*$ is smooth as well?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician I made another update.